# Scroll bar when scroll right i need the element always stay in the right

Tags: javascript, css

I have a situation:

in this page the bordered label in red in the right side which is the default of a table
[image]

And when i moved the sroll bar to the right the bordered label in red move to the center
[image]

The problem is i don`t need the bordered labeled in red to move wherever in scrolled right or left.
what i mean is i need that bordered labeled in red to stay on the right when scrolled right or left.

This is the table Code:

```
   <table class="table table-striped datatable-responsive overflow-auto" id="table">
```

and im just thinking to right a function like

```
function whenScrolled()
{
   var element = document.getElementbyId("labelborderedinred");
   //set the position of element current position + new position?
}
```

the element of red labeled on top

```
#table_length
```

the element of red labeled below

```
#table_paginate
```

Any idea is pretty much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe try giving the table a width such as 100% and then the rows inside fit-content with overflow auto, to only create the scrollbar for the rows instead of the entire table

Comment: Give to community more details, css and html of the table. Are you using some js extension such as Datatable?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. when i check this element i found out that the element id of that particular red labeled id `#table_length` and `#table_paginate` in bootstrap

Comment: could you provide a fiddle of the "working" table? this would make it easier to adjust some code

Comment: i think it is so hard for me to create a fiddle i am using .net mvc4. only i need is if how to manage that situation. but anyway thanks

Comment: so on scroll you just want that previous next section always stick to its position on the right? right?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you want is abit tricky, yuou need to have the HTML structure to get this done,if you keep the HTML structure like the example below, you can do it with the CSS only. you need to play with your css a bit to as I am not aware of your table data

```css
.table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;min-width: 1000px;}
td {background: #ddd;}
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.tableWrapper {
      position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.nextPrevious {
  position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="tableWrapper">
<table class="table table-striped datatable-responsive overflow-auto" id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="nextPrevious">Next previous Div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: appreciated the target solution of this answer.

Comment: is this the way you can modify your HTML ? is it useful for you?